# I am looking to grab a URL and exclude a word using Applescript

Tags: macos, curl, grep, applescript

I need help with a script. I want to grab a URL and exclude a word. the word below 'mydomaingoeshere, is where you put your full url. An example, if I pull the title from a URL I would like to exclude any word I want to from the title.

```
do shell script "curl mydomaingoeshere/ | grep -i \"<title>\""
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I do this:

```
curl www.google.com
```

I get this

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>302 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=ExnKVMbHKMbEaJ7hgOAC">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

but if, for some reason, I don't like the word `TITLE`, I do this:

```
curl www.google.com | sed 's/TITLE//g'
```

which uses `sed` to substitute/replace (`s`) the word `TITLE` (or whatever occurs between the first pair of `//`) with nothing (what appears between the second pair of `//`) globally (`g`) wherever it occurs on any line

```
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<>302 Moved</></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>302 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&amp;ei=vRnKVLffGMjDaNnFgeAI">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
```

If you are looking at your mentioned dictionary site, and want to grab the *HTML TITLE* but remove the words `Find`, `the` and `and`:

```
curl dictionary.reference.com | grep -i "<title>" | sed -E 's/Find|the|and//g'
```

you need the extra `-E` to say you want to be able to use the `|` to specify alternations.

Comment: Thanks, if you where to use the script I put up and use this domain: http://dictionary.reference.com/ the title that is pulled from this I want to exclude the words: (find, the, and) as an example.

Comment: Mark, thank you. That works, it was giving me a headache, I only got myself a mac last week. I'm trying to get my head around Applescript, thanks again.

Comment: No problems, that is actually `bash` (Bourne Again Shell) and `Unix` rather than Applescript - since it is invoked through `do shell script`.

Comment: @user3401094 if you're new to OS X & Apple "native" scripting, check out [JavaScript for Automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/). Apple made a javascript binding that does everything Apple's insanely stupid AppleScript language does, but far easier to grok for folks coming from a "normal" programming background. The only downside is that it's limited to Yosemite for deployments.